# Event loop is closed. Вызывается после закрытия дискорд бота

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, asyncio

Всем привет. Есть довольно необычная проблема. Я написал дискорд бота. Он спокойно функционирует и работает запросы обрабатывает. Но есть одно но. После завершения (выключения) бот выдает ошибку.

```
    Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001ED5B3B1F30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001ED5B3B1F30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Семен Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Семён Орехов\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Бот выдает такую ошибку после завершения программы. Как ее исправить?
Решения вроде:

1. Поменяй токен
2. Токен не валидный

и все такое, не помогли.
Если токен был бы не валидным, бот бы не работал.
Единственное я улучшил все библиотеки которые были. Сам discord, aiohttp и asyncio. Но к результату не привели. С чем такая проблема может быть связана?
Код бота, пример:

```
import discord

    TOKEN = 'Токен'
    class MyClient(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')


client = MyClient()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: А это разве так не должно быть?

Comment: Увы нет не должно быть. Бота я запускал ранее. Все прекрасно работало. Мне пришлось переустановить ОС на новую. Код заранее сохранил. И вот снова запустил, а тут такое.